# Suggestion for Eurostile-like font

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

I'm currently re-designing an unified layout for my resume, portfolio, business card, and so on.

Until now, I've used Eurostile as my preferred font, but I'd like to switch to another with a free license (at least free for personal use)

What I'm trying to do is to convey the idea of elegant design and technical skill in an architectural context.

I'm non only interested in an open version  of this font (although, if someone knows some close alternatives, it would be nice to share), I'm looking for a font that shares its main features: elegant, technical, suitable both for titles and text bodies. Of course it should be sans serif, and, as a bonus, retain the slightly rounded-square appearance of Eurostile (but this is not strictly mandatory, as long as it has a technical and elegant look).

Comment: How about the sans-serif [Jura Font](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/jura1) family licensed under the *SIL Open Font License* ? :)

Comment: Just FYI—free for personal use doesn't really cover business cards etc.

Comment: @elegent Thanks for your suggestion, that font is really awesome.

Answer (score 8):

I've rounded down some alternatives:

- [Jura](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Jura)
- [Titillium](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Titillium)
- [Esphimere](http://www.dafont.com/esphimere.font)
- [Exo](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/exo)
- [Exo 2](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/exo-2)
- [Enigmatic](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Enigmatic)
- [Aero Matics](http://www.dafont.com/it/aero-matics.font) (Especially the Light version)
- [Saira](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Saira)

Comment: I'd say you get what you pay for in terms of elegance. There are hardly any free fonts that don't look like free fonts. Especially when printed on paper.

Answer (score 1):

I used Michroma:

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Michroma

And in case  you want some heavy/extrabold style you might be interested in Montserrat:

https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/montserrat

Answer (score 0):

Arimo is like a more Grotesk version of Eurostile by my judgement

https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Arimo

Comment: How is this any better than the fonts suggested in the other answer?

Comment: @Luciano 'Better' is subjective. I'm simply providing an alternative font

Comment: Thanks, but this font looks too much like "your-generic-sans-serif" and is not what I'm really looking for.

Answer (score 0):

From the original description, Magistral may be a better alternative than many of the others mentioned here, when it comes to preserving the "rounded-square appearance" of Eurostile, while having it's own unique identity.
https://fontzone.net/font-details/pt-magistral-bold-cyrillic

Answer (score 0):

We can usually find libre fonts that resembles popular commercial fonts in LaTeX and Linux communities. This includes Eurostyle.

[Thanks to this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/typography/comments/rzn13q/looking_for_a_font_similar_to_eurostyle_but/), I became aware that [**the QualiType font collection**](http://luc.devroye.org/fonts-26839.html), available under [SIL Open Font License](http://luc.devroye.org/Qualitype-License.txt), contains [QT Eurotype](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/qteurotype/) which looks *really* close:

[image: QT eurotype screenshot]