# What characteristics define a technical typeface?

Tags: typefaces, terminology

I was reading [this other question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/69692/suggestion-for-eurostile-like-font) in GD.SE and suddenly realized that I don't know what exactly defines a technical typeface. It is very clear to me what defines a serif / sans-serif / cursive, but how can I describe a technical font like FF Din or Eurostile or the others depicted below? Or am I just digging too much and these are simply "geometrical" sans-serif fonts?

[image: Eurostile]

[image: Exo]

[image: Center]

[image: Din]

Comment: AFAIK 'technical' isn't really an established classification. Just a verb you could use to describe a typeface, and not a very well defined one (in terms of typefaces) at that.

Comment: @CAI i would argue there is.

Comment: If you search for ['technical fonts'](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=technical+fonts&source=lnms&tbm=isch) you get something very different.

Comment: @joojaa I agree with your definition, but I don't expect everyone does (seen from that search result). I've not seen any authority use 'technical' as a general classification for fonts. It may be used in certain contexts but not universally.

Comment: @CAI Yes but im not really surprised not many people in graphic design understands standardization efforts. But if you are a  typographicist then there is no better place to get a name than being on the standardization panel of a new standard font for some use.

Comment: when I worked with engineering we used the Din type with pen and ruler. We just didn't have a classification for it.

Comment: @Luciano yes and we drew ISO fonts, tough i was the last person to volunteer for hand drawing classes.

Comment: I'm not sure what that has to do with a font being classified as 'technical'. Unless there is a standard for font *classifications*?

Comment: @CAI that's what technical means. Words can have any meaning you wish, nothing says serif font has to mean anything either. Just because something is misused does not mean it has to lack a definition.

Comment: Serif is a universally accepted classification of fonts, that's what gives it meaning. I could say blue means red that doesn't make it true. That is what the word technical means, yes, I'm not arguing over the meaning of the word, I'm arguing it's not a generally accepted classification of fonts, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @CAI https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_lettering its not very far to say that a font based on technical lettering is a technical font.

Comment: @joojaa that's a fair argument. Like I said, I actually agree with your definition I just don't think it's a generally accepted definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Definition:

**technical /teknək(ə)l/**

- Involving, or as used in applied and industrial sciences.

#### A Technical font

Technical would be a standardized font for drawing technical documents, road signage, license plates etc. Or a font that mimics [technical lettering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_lettering). This is not widely known definition but it is defined enough to have a semi accurate meaning, just do not expect all graphics designers agree with this.

Examples of this would be [osifont](https://www.openhub.net/p/osifont) which is a font based on the ISO 3098 standard which defines how letters are to be drawn in technical drawings. Technical drawings should use a font based on this specification, sometimes mandated to use. The idea is that anybody can construct a font like this. Also they were originally hand lettered. Different counties used to have their own standards.

[image]

**Image 1**: Lettering font as defined by standard.

DIN (Deutsches Institut für Normung) also happens to be the name of the German standardization organization. First DIN fonts (DIN 1451) were originally commissioned 1936 for road and railway signage. And have many variants and standards related to them. Does not get much more technical than standardization, right. (the font standard is available [here](http://www.din.de/en/getting-involved/standards-committees/natg/standards/wdc-beuth:din21:8327080/quote))

So the fonts have a very engineeringly background. And possibly quite many fonts have been influenced by direct standards work.

Comment: Unfortunately i no longer have access to standards for free so i can not show a sample of the contents in DIN 1451-2 for example. If anybody does a picture would be nice

Comment: something from [here](http://www.typografie.info/3/page/Schriften/fonts.html/_/din-1451-r214) perhaps?

Comment: @Luciano Yes but its not a first hand source.

Comment: This is the answer. Googling "technical fonts" will bring up, more often than not, "technicalish" fonts. When I was a wee lad, and took "Drafting," one of the first lessons was how to draw letters.